# What is the best practise for providing a method/class/component that supports cancellation?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

How do you design a method/class that should support cancellation of the operation?

I realized that I never do that in a consistent manner and I want to change that.

Some of the things I have used:

- a boolean property on the class IsCancelled that I synchronize internally. sometimes I have a CanCancel property if the operation cannot be canceled at any given time
- pass a Func< bool > delegate that I repeatedly call to see if the operation has been canceled.
- terminate the thread manually - although this is definitely bad practise

How do you normally do that?

Answer (score 2):

I would go for the [`CancellationTokenSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.aspx) and using its associated [`CancellationToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx)
as a means for signalling cancellation. This is new in .Net Framework v4.

The concept is that the `CancellationTokenSource` simply calls Cancel and your code can share `CancellationToken`s on which you regular inspect the `IsCancellationRequested` property in it. This should especially be the case in tight loops or longer running operations, so as to allow your code to stop in a timely fashion.

The added bonus is that even blocked threads blocked due to a wait on a `SemaphoreSlim`, `ManualResetEventSlim` can be signalled to gracefully exit, since these classes accept a `CancellationToken` in their `Wait` method in .Net Framework v4

For example have a look at: [ManualResetEventSlim.Wait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270618.aspx) that has overloads accepting a `CancellationToken`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer to use the `IsCancelled` property idea. Your background thread method can check it at the appropriate times, do any cleanup as needed, and terminate the operation. If you're using a callback method when the thread finishes, it's easy to check the property and see if it's valid or not. I've used framework worker thread classes that used this strategy in the past, and it's worked well.

Comment: did you ever implement this for a single method, instead of a class?
The thing with the IsCancelled is that I keep reimplementing that in every class I need it. would be good to have a single implementation for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Go back to the use case: what is the behavior you're trying to provide?  If you have an asynchronous operation that you want to cancel, then you probably can best implement a method that lets you notify the other threadt via a flag or a semaphore.  Sending a signal is a nice method to get it's attention, although I haven't looked into C#'s handling of signals.  If you need to be able to cancel and undo, the Command pattern comes in handy.